# JPG to PDF Nautilus script (using ImageMagick)

Tags: python, imagemagick, nautilus

After searching for one without success, I decided to make my own script to convert selected JPEG files in one single PDF.

**Here's the code (made with Python):**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os

n = " ".join(os.environ["NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS"].splitlines())

os.system("convert " + n + " out.pdf")
```

The problem with this script is that it doesn't work if the files you want to convert are in a directory which name has spaces (let's say `/home/myuser/My Photos/1/`).

Is there any way I could fix this?

Answer (score 4):

```
n = " ".join("'%s'" % f for f in os.environ["NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS"].splitlines())
```

Remember to sanitize your filenames, otherwise a maliciously crafted name can make the script execute code on our machine.

Better yet, use the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module instead of `os.system()`.

```
subprocess.call ([ "convert" ] + os.environ["NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS"].splitlines() + [ "out.pdf" ])
```

Comment: Hi! The code worked perfectly, thanks! Just a couple of questions: Could you explain what does exactly your code do? and How can I use subprocess.call? I tried subprocess.call(["convert", n, "out.pdf"]) but it didn't work for some reason.

Comment: Reick: it puts quotes around filenames, so that they are recognized as a single argument by the shell even if they contain spaces.